# How can i find the velocities after the collision on this oblique collision problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, collision

I found this excercise in my textbook but i couldnt finish it.

Object $A$ with mass $m_1=m$ and velicity $u=12 m/s$ collides with object $B$ with mass $m_2=2m$ and velocity $u'=0$. After the collision object $A$ is moving with velocity $V_A$ and an angle of $30°$ with  $u$. After the collision object $B$ is moving with velocity $V_B$ and an angle of $60°$ with $u$

Find $V_A$ and $V_B$

My first thought was applying Pythagoras theorem on the momentum vectors so we have
 $(P_A')^2+(P_B')^2=(P_A)^2 \Rightarrow 4m^2V_B^2+m^2V_A^2=144m^2 \Rightarrow 4V_B^2+V_A^2=144 $ . Is my thought correct? And if it is, how should i proceed? Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Nikos and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this page in the site help](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more on what topics you can ask about here.

Comment: Draw the momentum triangle and use trigonometry.

Comment: I tried that, can you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a non-elastic collision in 2D, define a 2D coordinate system (x in the direction of original motion) and break your vector momentum equation into two component equations.  Then solve for the two unknowns.